# min_tag_id of Instagram API recent hashtag does not really return data from that tag ID forward

Tags: instagram

I have a process that gets the recent posts from instagram with a specific hashtag. I am using the endpoint tag//media/recent. This service is running every minute.

https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/mystorysg/media/recent?client_id=XX&min_tag_id=1385902563687

For some reason, our service stopped last Dec 1, and was just rectified today, Dec 5. The last min tag id that was obtained was 1385902563687 on Dec 1. Using the endpoint, it's now only returning the latest posts made today, Dec 5.

Is there another way to retrieve the posts from a past tag id and forward?

Comment: I realise that the only way is to use the max_tag_id, and move backwards from a current tag ID. To obtain the current tag ID, just call the endpoint without the params min and max.

Comment: @J Armaggedon - I don't get any current tag id in pagination for this endpoint [https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/mytag/media/recent?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx]. Here is the pagination part of response: {       u'pagination': {u'next_min_id': u'1393026916335', u'deprecation_warning': u'next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead', u'min_tag_id': u'1393026916335'}